# Encrypted replication between normal CouchDB and Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, security, python, encryption, couchdb

this is a very special question. Currently I'm starting to develop a new online shop using Python (Flask). I want to use CouchDB to store (and sync) new orders. But CouchDB does not encrypt the replication as far as I know.

Is it possible to use Python to get authentication with OAuth an start a replication via  https://couchdb.one.ubuntu.com between CouchDB and the UbuntuOne Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Desktopcouch does replication between a CouchDB (on your desktop) and https://couchdb.one.ubuntu.com, and that will work from any CouchDB; the CouchDB that desktopcouch runs is not something special.

To start a replication between a CouchDB of your choice and Ubuntu One, use the Couch replication API:

POST /_replicate HTTP/1.1

```
{
  "source":"example-database",
  "target":{
    "url": "https://couchdb.one.ubuntu.com/u%2Fabc%2Fdef%2F123456%2Fexample-database",
    "auth": {
      "oauth": {
        "consumer_key": "xxx",
        "consumer_secret": "xxx",
        "token": "xxx",
        "token_secret": "xxx"
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

You can find example code which actually kicks off this replication from Python in couchdb_io.py in the desktopcouch tree.